# Creating HTML from XML v/s JAVA object

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt

I am trying to create HTML file from the result of an execution. The result is in the form of XML. There are few transformers that I can use to transform XML to HTML using XSLT file.

Other thing I will also have is the JAVA object of result which I can use for converting it to HTML.

Which of the above two approach is better and is there any API that I can use to convert java object to HTML other than XSLT or FILE I/O.

any one help?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to go by xml (either directly or generated from your java object by jaxb).

In principle the templating frameworks (Velocity, Freemarker ...) can let you prepare a template into which you can inject your java object and render the response as you whish. But personally I think it will be easier/simple just to transform the xml that you already have